# How to make pine script bactesting with specify price

Tags: pine-script

I want to create a pine script in trading view, to simulate the pairs of USDT/IDRT.

1. I want to buy USDT when the price is 13.850 and sell them when the price is 14.400
2. And how to backtesting them, within 1 year ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from this:

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)
strategy.entry("E", strategy.long, limit = 13850)
strategy.exit("X", limit = 14400)
```